# How is it that a tachyon is faster than $c$?

Tags: faster-than-light, tachyon

I remember reading that a [tachyon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyon) is faster than light, but am still confused as to how and if they could exist in our universe?

Comment: Did you read [Wikipedia's take](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyon) on this? In any case, it would benefit your question to be more precise about *which aspect* of the idea of the tachyon you are confused, I think.

Comment: related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/61126/

Answer (score 1):

*If* there were a particle that traveled faster than $c$, we would call it a tachyon. Such a particle would indicate that we fundamentally misunderstand the structure of spacetime, since travel faster than $c$ is forbidden in special and general relativity. There is no experimental evidence for any such particle.

More realistically, tachyons indicate problems with a theoretical model. I have had discussions with string theorists who are working to modify the such-and-such model so that it no longer predicts tachyons.

Comment: *Such a particle would indicate that we fundamentally misunderstand the structure of spacetime, since travel faster than c is forbidden in special and general relativity.* Not true. There are specific issues with FTL in SR, but this is not a correct statement of any of them.

Comment: @BenCrowell I always appreciate your high standards for rigor and I look forward to your more careful answer. My point was mostly that tachyons are generally considered symptoms of a sick theory.